# Jupyter is not finding the "iris" file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I'm new at programming and I'm trying to import the Iris.csv datafile, so I downloaded it at Kaggle and the inserted this code in Jupyter Notebook:

```
import pandas as pd
iris = pd.read_csv("../Iris.csv")
```

and the following error occurs:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../Iris.csv'
```

(The error message is actually huge but I can't post it entirely)

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you have to provide the full path  of your downloaded file : example "C:\\Users\\name\\Downloads\\Iris.csv"

Comment: It helped, Anky! Thanks so much. I'm not so used with the concept of paths, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice for reading a CSV file in python is to add **"r"** before the directory, as mentioned in the example below.

```
import pandas as pd
iris = pd.read_csv(r"../Iris.csv")
```

In Python, backslash is used to signify special characters. r stands for "raw" and will cause backslashes in the string to be interpreted as actual backslashes rather than special characters.

**NOTE:**
If the issue remains, then try to keep notebook and CSV in same directory before executing the above code.